# TinyMCE text Editor RTL direction toolbar list box button wrong direction

Tags: tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE textEditor.

I'm using it with `directionality: "rtl"` and `theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "right"` ,
My problem is that button that are list boxs like `Font Size` or `Font Family` are opening in the worng way - the are not in rtl position there for they are not opening in the right direction!

How can i set these list boxs to be aligned in an rtl position ?

Thank's In Advance.